# Iterar Array de Objetos y retornar sus Key,Value según parámetro:?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

espero estén excelente... estoy haciendo unos ejercicios para ingresar a un Bootcamp pero llevo varios días estancado en uno.

```
/*Debés crear una función llamada `oneProperty` que reciba un arreglo de objetos como
parámetro y un string. Deberá retornar un nuevo arreglo de objetos, teniendo como
parámetro la propiedad que fue pasada como string.----------------
Ejemplo:

var arreglo = [ { name: “lucas”, edad: 20 }, { name: “santi”, edad: 22 } ]
- oneProperty(arreglo, “edad”) debe retornar [ { edad: 20 }, { edad: 22 } ]
- oneProperty(arreglo, “name”) debe retornar [ { name: “lucas”}, { name: “santi” } ]
 */
arreglo=[{ "name": "lucas", edad: 20 }, { "name": "santi", edad: 22 }] ;

let oneProperty=(arr,palabra)=>{
    for (objetos of arr){
        Object.entries(objetos).map(propiedades=>{
            var [key,value]=propiedades;
            if(palabra==key||value){
                console.log(key,value)
            }
        })
    }
}
oneProperty(arreglo,"edad")
```

Aparte de esto, algún consejo mas? No se porque siento que tendré que estudiar JS desde 0. Me frustra un poco no poder avanzar y/o recordar métodos antes vistos pero que no se me pasaron por la mente usarlos en el ejercicio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solamente defines un nuevo_array[] donde vas a insertar los resultados y recorres arr[] para asignar en un nuevo objeto la palabra como propiedad y su valor de cada elemento.

```
let oneProperty=(arr,palabra)=>{
    var nuevo_array = [];
    arr.forEach(function (elemento) {
        var objeto = {};
        objeto[palabra] = elemento[palabra];
        nuevo_array.push(objeto);
    });
    return nuevo_array;
}
console.log(oneProperty(arreglo,"edad"))
```

Answer (score 2):

creo que puedes conseguirlo de una manera más sencilla:

```
        let oneProperty = (arr,palabra)=>{ 
          arr.map((propiedades) => {
          if ((propiedadesr.hasOwnProperty(palabra))) {
            return propiedades[palabra];
          }
       });
     }
```

Un saludo y espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo. Primeramente crea el arreglo que devolverá tu función:

```
let arregloNuevo = [];
```

Para cada objeto del arreglo de entrada `arr`:

```
for (let objeto of arr) {...}
```

Pregunta si el objeto tiene la propiedad que te pasaron por palabra:

```
if(objeto.hasOwnProperty(palabra)) {...}
```

Si la tiene, entonces simplemente agrega un nuevo objeto con esa propiedad al arreglo de salida:

```
arregloNuevo.push({[palabra]: objeto[palabra]});
```

Si unimos cada uno de los pasos quedaría:

```js
let arreglo = [{ "name": "lucas", edad: 20 }, { "name": "santi", edad: 22 }];

let oneProperty = (arr, palabra) => {
    let arregloNuevo = [];
    for (let objeto of arr) {
        if(objeto.hasOwnProperty(palabra)){
            arregloNuevo.push({[palabra]: objeto[palabra]});
        }
    }
    return arregloNuevo;
}

console.log(oneProperty(arreglo, "edad"));
console.log(oneProperty(arreglo, "name"));
```

Solo practica, practica, practica y no te rindas, ese es el único consejo que necesitas.Saludos!